# Example of a connected topological space with an open singleton set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I was working on a problem that asked me to find an example of a topological space $X$ that satisfies the following:

$X$ is a connected, $X-\{p\}$ is disconnected and $\{p\}$ is open.

I have been unable to find such a space and I have almost convinced myself that there can exist no such space. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How about something like $X = \{ a, b, p \}$ with the topology where $U$ is open if and only if $p \in U$ or $U = \emptyset$?  (Then the subspace topology on $\{ a, b \}$ is the discrete topology.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: Bravo! That does it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As soon as the space is $T_1$ we cannot have such a space, as then such an open singleton is a non-trivial closed-and-open subset of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

The included point topology on a set will work: let $X$ be a set (say infinite) and let $p \in X$ and define the included point topology $$\mathcal{T}_p = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{A \subseteq X: p \in A\}$$

One easily checks this is a topology and $\{p\}$ is open while in $X\setminus \{p\}$ all singletons are relatively open as $q\neq p$ implies $$\{q\} = \{p,q\} \cap (X \setminus \{p\}$$
is open in that subspace, making $X\setminus \{p\}$ infinite discrete and hence disconnected.

$X$ itself is connected as any two non-empty open sets must intersect in $p$, so there can be decomposition of $X$ into two non-empty disjoint open sets.